# How can I process a tarfile with a Python multiprocessing pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tarfile

I'm trying to process the contents of a tarfile using `multiprocessing.Pool`.  I'm able to successfully use the ThreadPool implementation within the multiprocessing module, but would like to be able to use processes instead of threads as it would possibly be faster and eliminate some changes made for Matplotlib to handle the multithreaded environment.  I'm getting an error that I suspect is related to processes not sharing address space, but I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_tarfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    test_multiproc()
  File "test_tarfile.py", line 24, in test_multiproc
    pool.map(read_file, files)
  File "/ldata/whitcomb/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 225, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/ldata/whitcomb/epd-7.1-2-rh5-x86_64/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 522, in get
    raise self._value
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

The actual program is more complicated, but this is an example of what I'm doing that reproduces the error:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool, Pool
import StringIO
import tarfile

def write_tar():
    tar = tarfile.open('test.tar', 'w')
    contents = 'line1'
    info = tarfile.TarInfo('file1.txt')
    info.size = len(contents)
    tar.addfile(info, StringIO.StringIO(contents))
    tar.close()

def test_multithread():
    tar   = tarfile.open('test.tar')
    files = [tar.extractfile(member) for member in tar.getmembers()]
    pool  = ThreadPool(processes=1)
    pool.map(read_file, files)
    tar.close()

def test_multiproc():
    tar   = tarfile.open('test.tar')
    files = [tar.extractfile(member) for member in tar.getmembers()]
    pool  = Pool(processes=1)
    pool.map(read_file, files)
    tar.close()

def read_file(f):
    print f.read()

write_tar()
test_multithread()
test_multiproc()
```

I suspect that the something's wrong when the `TarInfo` object is passed into the other process but the parent `TarFile` is not, but I'm not sure how to fix it in the multiprocess case.  Can I do this without having to extract files from the tarball and write them to disk?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not passing a `TarInfo` object into the other process, you're passing the result of `tar.extractfile(member)` into the other process where `member` is a `TarInfo` object. The `extractfile(...)` method returns a file-like object which has, among other things, a `read()` method which operates upon the original tar file you opened with `tar = tarfile.open('test.tar')`.

However, you can't use an open file from one process in another process, you have to re-open the file. I replaced your `test_multiproc()` with this:

```
def test_multiproc():
    tar   = tarfile.open('test.tar')
    files = [name for name in tar.getnames()]
    pool  = Pool(processes=1)
    result = pool.map(read_file2, files)
    tar.close()
```

And added this:

```
def read_file2(name):
    t2 = tarfile.open('test.tar')
    print t2.extractfile(name).read()
    t2.close()
```

and was able to get your code working.

Comment: Windows support: `if name == '__main__': test_multiproc()`. There's no fork in Windows, so the module gets imported in the new process initially under the name `'__parents_main__'`, and then the name gets changed back to `'__main__'`. So you can guard statements you don't want to run in the child processes by using an `if` block.

Comment: This works, but requires me to re-open the tarfile in every process.  Is there any other workaround that would allow read-only access to a file descriptor between processes?

Comment: I ended up setting a flag to pre-read the data before the multiple processes fork off.  Thank you!