# Fastest way to extract tar files using Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have to extract hundreds of tar.bz files each with size of 5GB. So tried the following code:

```
import tarfile
from multiprocessing import Pool

files = glob.glob('D:\\*.tar.bz') ##All my files are in D
for f in files:

   tar = tarfile.open (f, 'r:bz2')
   pool = Pool(processes=5)

   pool.map(tar.extractall('E:\\') ###I want to extract them in E
   tar.close()
```

But the code has type error:
TypeError: map() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)

How can I solve it?
Any further ideas to accelerate extracting?

Comment: I'm betting your problem here is the I/O rather than the code. The `map` error is clear: you have to provide a function and the list of parameters to that function. Your case: `map(extractall, [list, of, files])`

Comment: How can I provide the destination directory? map(extractall, [list, of, files])

Comment: Different targets to each file? `[(list, dest), (of, dest2), (files, dest3)]`. Same target? Create a `functools.partial` for the `extractall`.

Comment: Actually same target to each file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I process a tarfile with a Python multiprocessing pool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250264/how-can-i-process-a-tarfile-with-a-python-multiprocessing-pool)

Comment: Why use python for this at all? If you've got cygwin, you have `xargs -P`, or (shudder) GNU parallel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to change `pool.map(tar.extractall('E:\\')` to something like  `pool.map(tar.extractall(),"list_of_all_files")`

Note that `map()` takes 2 argument first is a function , second is a iterable , and Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the results.

Edit : you need to pass a `TarInfo` object into the other process :

```
def test_multiproc():
    files = glob.glob('D:\\*.tar.bz2')
    pool  = Pool(processes=5)
    result = pool.map(read_files, files)


def read_files(name):

 t = tarfile.open (name, 'r:bz2')
 t.extractall('E:\\')
 t.close()

>>>test_multiproc()
```

Comment: E is the destination directory to put the extracted file.

Comment: So is not it necessary to use tar = tarfile.open (f, 'r:bz2')?

Comment: yes and i think instead that you can use `TarFile.getmembers()` inside `tar.extractall`

Comment: Sorry I could not understand what you said; waiting for your complete solution.

Comment: i edit the answer , could you pls try it and give me the result ?

Answer (score 4):

Define a function that extract a single tar file. Pass that function and a tar file list to `multiprocessing.Pool.map`:

```
import glob
import tarfile
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool


def extract(path, dest):
    with tarfile.open(path, 'r:bz2') as tar:
        tar.extractall(dest)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    files = glob.glob('D:\\*.tar.bz')
    pool = Pool(processes=5)
    pool.map(partial(extract, dest='E:\\'), files)
```

Comment: Also, you could have a look to concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor